# AWS CloudFormation create parameterized CodeCommit repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, cookiecutter

I have a CloudFormation template which creates a simple CodeCommit repository and places some code in it, based on a ZIP file in S3. However, the code inside this ZIP file has been parameterized using [Cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/). Right now the CloudFormation template just pushes the code to the repository, but is there any way to push the *parameterized* code to the repository, i.e. by defining the values of the parameters? This would require running the *cookiecutter* command through the CloudFormation template.

Comment: Could this help maybe: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html?

Comment: Not sure how I would use this? I’m quite new to AWS in general, I have mostly experience in Azure. Basically I would need to run a CodeBuild which I have already created, but I can’t seem to find a way to do it via a CloudFormation template. The only examples I find create a CodeBuild but I already have one created and would like to reuse it multiple times, just with different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> This would require running the cookiecutter command through the CloudFormation template.

Well, you either can create a small script that does that and updates your file in S3, or create a proper CI/CD pipeline with [CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html) action. The action would run your `cookiecutter` to setup your code for publication in S3. There is also [AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CloudFormation.html) action which could fallow the CodeBuild action to deploy your template with the parameterized code.

There are also other options, one already mentioned in the comments using custom resources.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I have indeed already built a CodeBuild action to run the Cookiecutter command and it works perfectly. However, the part I struggle with is the integration with Sagemaker. I would like to have the newly created repository show up as a "project" in Sagemaker as if you would use the user interface of Sagemaker to create a new project (Sagemaker components & registries > Create new project). Any idea on how this could be achieved? It seems I need to create a custom "organization template" and this can only be done through CloudFormation.

Comment: To put it differently: is it possible to just run an existing CodeBuild from a CloudFormation template? I can only find examples where a CodeBuild is created from the CloudFormation template, but in my case the CodeBuild is already there, so I just need to run it with the right parameters.

Comment: @vdvaxel `is it possible to just run an existing CodeBuild from a CloudFormation template?` - yes you can, but this requires a custom resource in CloudFormation.

Comment: @vdvaxel How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?